# How to extract common part in Maven profiles

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

In my `pom.xml` I have defined couple of profiles to run my Spring Boot application under the Oracle WebLogic:

```
    <profile>
        <id>wls-1</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <properties>

        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>wls-2</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <properties>

        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>wls-3</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <properties>

        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>tomcat1</id>
        <properties>

        </properties>
    </profile>
```

as you can see in in every new `wls` profile I need to define dependencies to use provide scope (otherwise deploy will fail because of some tomcat resources).
But still I have there some other profiles which will not use this `wls-common` part

Is there a way how I can define some `wls-common` profile which will be automatic used from there profile **WITHOUT** changing my `mvn` command? I know I can chain profile in `mvn -P p1,p2` or with property `-Dp1=wls` but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Why you need embed Tomcat inside WebLogic?

Comment: I need to changed compile scope from provided to not use tomcat resources in wls. Best part will be exclude this whole dependency but then again I will need to add some javax.servlet-api dependency so this should be the easier change

Answer (score 0):

In all your profiles define the properties which will activate the specific profile and place all of them in common profile.

This will however require form you to change your command from `mvn -Pwls-1` to `mvn -Dwls-1`

```
<profile>
 <id>wls-1</id>
 <activation>
   <property>
     <name>wls-1</name>
   </property>
 </activation>
 ...
</profile> 
<profile>
    <id>common</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>wls-1</name>
        <name>wls-2</name>
        <name>wls-3</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Comment: but when I want to run my application under tomcat profile then I need to set this property in mvn command to not change my dependency

Comment: Sorry, I think you cannot. There seems to be no way to fire activation a profile from another one. The trick with the properties is the only one I know. It will also require from you to change the command

Answer (score 0):

You cannot activate a profile from another profile. You can only activate them through external means like command line, marker files, operation system.